VirtualBoxにて、コピー＆ペーストを行いたい。
ホストOS： Windows 11 23H2 (OS ビルド 22631.4169)
ゲストOS : Ubuntuubuntu-ja-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso
VirtualBox： 7.0.18 r162988 (Qt5.15.2)
ホストOS(windowsのdesktop)からゲストOS(ubuntuのデスクトップ)へファイルの移動を行いました。
しかし、エラー文もなく、コピーアンドペーストができません。
どのように環境構築すれば、コピーアンドペースを実行できますでしょうか？
[実施したこと]
1.Extension Packの導入
ダウンロード先：
https://www.oracle.com/jp/virtualization/technologies/vm/downloads/virtualbox-downloads.html#extpack
手順：
https://www.nakivo.com/blog/how-to-install-virtualbox-extension-pack/
2.VirtualBoxのGuest Additionsの追加
手順：
https://kimamani89.com/2020/08/14/%E3%81%84%E3%81%84%E5%8A%A0%E6%B8%9B%E8%A6%9A%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B%E3%80%81virtualbox%E3%81%AEguest-additions%E3%81%AE%E8%BF%BD%E5%8A%A0%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95/
3.クリップボードを共有するボタンの押下
手順：
https://pc-karuma.net/virtualbox-clipboard-share/

4年前の古い記事ですがドラッグ&ドロップは別の設定があるようですが。ドラッグ＆ドロップの共有設定 ただしCopilotに聞いたら特定のOSの特定の版数によっては制限がある場合があるそうです。例えばドラッグ＆ドロップの設定 のUbuntu 20.04LTSではデスクトップとファイルブラウザ間のドラッグ&ドロップが禁止

VirtualBox の「クリップボードを共有」ではファイルの移動等はできません。
この機能はあくまで「テキストのコピーペースト」が出来るようになるだけです。
ホスト OS とゲスト OS 間でファイルのやり取りをしたい場合には、VirtualBox の「共有フォルダ」機能を使う方法があります。
参考:
VirtualBoxでファイルを共有するための共有フォルダを設定しよう！
